# PostgreSQL change the default naming convention for the constraints

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to bump the existing PG instance to the 12/13 version, but there's an integration test checking that our migrations will succeed - those are running flyway on the clean database in docker from scratch and some of the migrations are failing on v 12/13, but they are all OK on 9.6/11.

There's a script

```
CREATE TABLE "position" (
  id               SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  account_number   VARCHAR(50)                      NOT NULL,
  firm_id          INTEGER REFERENCES firm (id)     NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (account_number, firm_id) REFERENCES account (account_number, firm_id)
);
```

Foreign key (account_number, firm_id) is created with name `position_account_number_fkey` using PG 9.6 and PG 11.

The same script creates a foreign key with the name `position_account_number_firm_id_fkey` using PG 12/13.

QUESTION: Is there an easy way to use the naming convention from PG 9.6/11 on 12/13 servers?

Comment: Never rely on automatically generated names. Always provide your own names if you need stable ones - especially if you have tests that check those names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are absolutely right, but this is where we are now

Comment: There is no configuration setting that changes this behavior. You will have to do a version test and modify the checks accordingly.

Comment: roger that folks